# Is there info on how Mayans invented hard rubber?

Tags: chemistry, science

I know they had balls from the rubber trees mixed with morning glory flowers. A technology that was lost when the European colonizers came. But was there any info on who made this discovery and how?

Comment: See the Wikipedia article [Mesoamerican rubber balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesoamerican_rubber_balls) and the citations therein